# SQL Server installation error: "Cannot find group with identity"

Tags: sql-server, failed-installation

I've been getting the following error during SQL Server 2017 installation:

> "Cannot find group with identity
>   S-1-5-21-1957117185-995604489-4217650133-2632"

What can I do to fix it?

[image]

Comment: thank you! Did you get it installed?

Comment: @Brien Yes, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a SID [Security Identifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379571(v=vs.85).aspx).

Possible you are trying to use an account that doesn’t exist anymore, or you are breaking this requirement/limitation:

> You cannot run SQL Server services on a domain controller under a
>   local service account.

Have a read here:
[Installing SQL Server on a Domain Controller](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/hardware-and-software-requirements-for-installing-sql-server#DC_support)